# OR condition for optional binding?

Tags: swift3, option-type, unwrap, optional-binding

I've seen in `Swift 3.1` documentation that you can include several optional bindings in an `if` statement separated by commas, and that it behaves like an `AND` operator.

Let's say that I have two optional properties and I'd like to check which of them (or both) is/are not `nil`, unwrap the non-nil one(s), and then execute a block of code. Using this:

```
if let = property1, let = property2 {
   // Some task to do with unwrapped property 
}
```

only executes the `if` statement block if both properties are unwrapped (`AND` condition). But for me, it would be enough to have at least one of those properties being non-nil to execute the code in the `if` statement block (`OR` condition). But if I do like this:

```
if property1 != nil || property2 != nil {
   // Some task to do with non-nil property
}
```

But then I don't have the unwrapped value of the non-nil property. I'd like to have the unwrapped value available in the `if` statement block of code to avoid optional chaining there.

Which would be the best practice and most compact way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think this is possible in a single line (like `if let x = y || let z = a {}`). Logically it wouldn't make sense, because you would end up in a state where both variables would remain optional (if either is unwrapped, you don't know which is unwrapped or if both are). I think you'll need to take some other approach to this problem. I think the simplest form would be something like

```
if let unwrappedProperty1 = property1 {
    handleProperty(unwrappedProperty1)
} else if let unwrappedProperty2 = property2 {
    handleProperty(unwrappedProperty2)
}
```

or you could do something like

```
if let unwrappedProperty = property1 ?? property2 {
    handleProperty(unwrappedProperty)
}
```

which would give priority to property1

Answer (score 3):

How about this.

```
if let property = property1 ?? property2 {
    // non nil property (any one of the two)
}
```

if `property1` and `property2` both have values `property1` gets the precedence.